# What is a satellite trap?

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication-satellite

I keep hearing about satellite traps, which have something to do with receiving and transmitting satellite communications, but I can't seem to find a definition.

The securityaffairs.co blogpost [Hack Satellite Connection and Surf Anonymously with High-speed Internet](https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/39308/hacking/hack-satellite.html) says:

> A Spanish-based security analyst demonstrated new satellite capturing traps that could allow to surf anonymously with High-speed Internet.

and

> In a presentation at the Black Hat security gathering in Arlington, Va., Tuesday, Spanish cybersecurity specialist Leonardo Nve introduced a mixed bag of traps for obtaining entrance to and abusing satellite Internet associations. Utilizing not even exactly $75 as a part of devices, Nve, a scientist with security firm S21Sec, says that he can catch Digital Video Broadcast (DVB) signs to get free rapid (extremely high speed) Internet.

But I still don't understand *what the trap actually is!* Is it something in space, or on the ground? Are there any aspects of traps that relate to how the satellite operates or orbits the Earth?

Comment: Can you provide a link to such a reference, or are you hearing this term from non-internet sources?

Comment: https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/39308/hacking/hack-satellite.html

Comment: Now that you have edited the acronym TRaP out of your question, my answer no longer applies :(

Comment: @OrganicMarble [it's there](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33486/12102), if you're interested let me know.

Comment: @SteveMucci I've moved your link back into your question where it belongs, quoted a bit of it, and elaborated on your question to emphasize the *Space Exploration* aspects of it. If it turns out not to have any SE aspects, then in that case it might be better to ask in [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the information in the question it's clear to me that those traps are illegal ground stations. Normally you need a subscription to get satellite internet. This researcher has found a way to decode the signals and get free access.

Answer (score 3):

The article doesn’t read like a native English speaker wrote it
(e.g. “utilizing not even exactly $75 as a part of devices...”).

In context I think “trap” means “hack” or “exploit” in the information security sense.